# Keyboard does not work any more (18.04, 4.15.0-20-generic) on Razer Blade laptop

Tags: keyboard, mouse, touchpad, 18.04

After booting the laptop, the keyboard does not work at all any more: in the login screen, none of the keys does anything. The touchpad can be used to move the mouse pointer, but clicking on a user name or an icon in the panel does not do anything either. When I boot into 4.13.0-39 instead, everything works as expected.

Oddly, if an external USB keyboard is attached when logging in, both the USB keyboard and the laptop keyboard work and the laptop keyboard continues to work after removing the external one.